# How to reverse a QList?

Tags: qt

I see [qCopy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qCopy), and [qCopybackward](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtalgorithms.html#qCopyBackward) but neither seems to let me make a copy in reverse order. `qCopybackward` only copies it in reverse order, but keeps the darn elements in the same order! All I want to do is return a copy of the list in reverse order. There **has** to be a function for that, right?

Comment: +1 for stating there has to be a function for it, totally agree. PS its open source, we all could go build it and submit it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you don't like the QTL, just use the STL. They might not have a Qt-ish API, but the STL API is rock-stable :) That said, `qCopyBackward` is just `std::copy_backward`, so at least they're consistent.

Answering your question:

```
template <typename T>
QList<T> reversed( const QList<T> & in ) {
    QList<T> result;
    result.reserve( in.size() ); // reserve is new in Qt 4.7
    std::reverse_copy( in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter( result ) );
    return result;
}
```

***EDIT 2015-07-21:*** Obviously (or maybe not), if you want a one-liner (and people seem to prefer that, looking at the relative upvotes of different answers after five years) and you have a non-`const` `list` the above collapses to

```
std::reverse(list.begin(), list.end());
```

But I guess the index fiddling stuff is better for job security :)

Comment: As long as the STL library works on the QList, that's fine. I just don't want to have to use an STL list. I think I tried this before, but I didn't know about the back_inserter so maybe that's what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, all Qt containers are STL `Sequence`s (though they might not meet higher-level concepts, due to missing functionality).

Comment: And `QList` has nothing to do with `std::list`. The former is a vector with efficient `push_front()` (a bit like `std::deque` and `std::vector` combined), and funny properties when `sizeof(T)>sizeof(void*)`, the latter is a doubly-linked list (`QLinkedList` in Qt speak). Go figure :/

Comment: Yeah... that through me off a bit at first. I was a bit hesitant to use QLists because I figured they'd have poor random access... but that's not really the case :)

Comment: For more generic goodness, you can make this function return other types: `template <typename ContainerType> ResultType reversed_copy(const ContainerType& in) { ContainerType result; ...` Or even give it a separate ResultType template argument to have it make a revised copy and change from one container type to another.

Answer (score 24):

Reverse your QList with a single line:

```
for(int k = 0; k < (list.size()/2); k++) list.swap(k,list.size()-(1+k));
```

Comment: @Lame-up-duck: Work's great for me when reversing a QStringList (non-const of course), what's your issue?

Comment: But it should, the middle element is just not swapped at all, which is fine, because it would be the middle element in the reversed list, too.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Is there no built-in way to do this with `qSort()`?  Seems like a big development oversight to not allow sorting in descending order.

Comment: Not sure when it got introduced, but it's now swapItemsAt instead of swap. Like so. 
         for(int k=0, s=list.size(), max=(s/2); k<max; k++) list.swapItemsAt(k,s-(1+k));

Answer (score 13):

[Rewrite from original]

It's not clear if OP wants to know "How [do I] reverse a QList?" or actually wants a reversed copy. User mmutz gave the correct answer for a reversed copy, but if you just want to reverse the QList in place, there's this:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
```

And then

```
std::reverse(list.begin(), list.end());
```

Or in C++11:

```
std::reverse(std::begin(list), std::end(list));
```

The beauty of the C++ standard library (and templates in general) is that the algorithms and containers are separate. At first it may seem annoying that the standard containers (and to a lesser extent the Qt containers) don't have convenience functions like `list.reverse()`, but consider the alternatives: Which is more elegant: Provide `reverse()` methods for all containers, or define a standard interface for all containers that allow bidirectional iteration and provide one `reverse()` implementation that works for all containers that support bidirectional iteration?

To illustrate why this is an elegant approach, consider the answers to some similar questions:

"How do you reverse a `std::vector<int>`?":

```
std::reverse(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

"How do you reverse a `std::deque<int>`?":

```
std::reverse(std::begin(deq), std::end(deq));
```

What about portions of the container?

"How do you reverse the first seven elements of a `QList`?": Even if the `QList` authors had given us a convenience `.reverse()` method, they probably wouldn't have given us this functionality, but here it is:

```
if (list.size() >= 7) {
    std::reverse(std::begin(list), std::next(std::begin(list), 7));
}
```

But it gets better: Because the iterator interface is the same as C pointer syntax, and because C++11 added the free `std::begin()` and `std::end` functions, you can do these:

"How do you reverse an array `float x[10]`?":

```
std::reverse(std::begin(x), std::end(x));
```

or pre C++11:

```
std::reverse(x, x + sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]));
```

(That is the ugliness that `std::end()` hides for us.)

Let's go on:
"How do you reverse a buffer `float* x` of size `n`?":

```
std::reverse(x, x + n);
```

"How do you reverse a null-terminated string `char* s`?":

```
std::reverse(s, s + strlen(s));
```

"How do you reverse a not-necessarily-null-terminated string `char* s` in a buffer of size `n`?":

```
std::reverse(s, std::find(s, s + n, '\0'));
```

Note that `std::reverse` uses `swap()` so even this will perform pretty much as well as it possibly could:

```
QList<QList<int> > bigListOfBigLists;
....
std::reverse(std::begin(bigListOfBigLists), std::end(bigListOfBigLists));
```

Also note that these should all perform as well as a hand-written loop since, when possible, the compiler will turn these into pointer arithmetic. Also, you can't cleanly write a reusable, generic, high-performance `reverse` function like this C.

Comment: I don't know... what's wrong with that? ;)  ie: is this really an answer to the question? if so - don't forget there are total n00bs on this site that may not understand what you're telling the Original Poster... would you mind explaining your answer a bit so that they understand what you're trying to tell the OP? :)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the Java style iterator. Complete example here ([http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.2/collection.html](http://doc.trolltech.com/2.3/collection.html)). Look for the word "reverse".

```
QList<int> list; // initial list

list << 1;
list << 2;
list << 3;

QList<int> rlist; // reverse list+

QListIterator<int> it(list);
while (it.hasPrevious()) {
    rlist << it.previous();
}
```

Comment: answer miss `it.toBack();` before while loop

Answer (score 11):

@Marc Jentsch's answer is good. And if you want to get an additional **30% performance boost** you can change his one-liner to:

```
for(int k=0, s=list.size(), max=(s/2); k<max; k++) list.swap(k,s-(1+k));
```

One a ThinkPad W520 with a QList of 10 million QTimers I got these numbers:

- reversing list stack overflow took 194 ms
- reversing list stack overflow with max and size took 136 ms

The boost is a result of

- the expression (list.size()/2) being calculated only once when initializing the loop and not after every step
- the expression list.size() in swap() is called only once when initializing the loop and not after every step

Comment: Not sure when it got introduced, but it's now swapItemsAt instead of swap. Like so. 
         for(int k=0, s=list.size(), max=(s/2); k<max; k++) list.swapItemsAt(k,s-(1+k));

Answer (score 6):

For standard library lists it would look like this

```
std::list<X> result;
std::copy(list.rbegin(), list.rend(), std::back_inserter(result));
```

Unfortunately, Qt doesn't have rbegin and rend functions that return reverse iterators (the ones that go from the end of the container to its begnning).  You may write them, or you can just write copying function on your own -- reversing a list is a nice excersize.  Or you can note that QList is actually an array, what makes writing such a function trivial.  Or you can convert the list to std::list, and use rbegin and rend.  Choose whatever you like.

Comment: Well, I have written my own function in the meantime, but this bothers me greatly. How could they have left that out? I was indeed looking for rbegin and rend but they seem to have left those out too (muttering something about bidirectional iterators?), even though they implemented everything else from STL.

Comment: FTR: `QList` has `rbegin()`/`rend()` starting with Qt 5.6.

Answer (score 6):

Reversing a QList is going to be O(n) however you do it, since QList isn't guaranteed to have its data stored contiguously in memory (unlike QVector).  You might consider just traversing the list in backwards order where you need to, or use something like a QStack which lets you retrieve the elements in the opposite order they were added.

Comment: Well I wasn't concerned about run-time, just thought a function should already exist so that I didn't have to write my own. Should be `n/2` though I think... not that the `/2` matters in Big-O.

Comment: +1 for "backwards order" :-) Why reverse if you use a for-loop anyways? (Although I'm not used to `i--`-loops.)

Comment: Eh? What does data storage have to do with anything? Reversing *any* list-like structure is *always* going to be O(N), unless it is specially optimized for this case and does some clever index indirection. (I doubt you'd run into any such implementations.)

In theory, a QList could be reversed faster than a QVector, since the items are stored indirectly and only the list of pointers needs to be reversed (i.e. not necessary to copy the underlying items). I don't know that Qt exposes API to make this possible, however.

Comment: My bad; list.swap will swap the pointers and not the underlying items... so the answers using list.swap are probably faster (especially for expensive-to-copy objects) than either std::reverse or if you have a QVector / std::vector instead of a QList.

Answer (score 0):

As of Qt 5.14 (circa 2020), `QList` provides a [constructor that takes iterators](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#QList-4), so you can just construct a reversed copy of the list with the reverse iterators of the source:

```
QList<int> backwards(forwards.rbegin(), forwards.rend());
```

Or if you want to be able to inline it, more generically (replace `QList<I>` with just `I` if you want to be super duper generic):

```
template <typename I> QList<I> reversed (const QList<I> &forwards) {
    return QList<I>(forwards.rbegin(), forwards.rend());
}
```

Which lets you do fun one-liners with temporaries like:

```
QString badDay = "reporter covers whale exploding";
QString worseDay = reversed(badDay.split(' ')).join(' ');
```